# How can I get PlotLegends to accept more than 8 entries in a column?

Tags: legending

I have graphics that would be easier to read if the legends matched the order of the curves, but I can't get PlotLegends to make a column having more than 8 items.

```
In[6]:= legends = Characters["abcdefghijk"]

Out[6]= {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k"}

In[8]:= LineLegend[legends, Automatic, LegendLayout -> "Column"]
```

[image]

Comment: try  `LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1}`?

Comment: Thanks @kglr, that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not use this command, but playing around this worked for your example. I do not know if there are other side-effect for this when used in actual application

```
f[x_]:=Grid[x]
LineLegend[legends,Automatic,LegendLayout->f]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you can also use the Grid to change it as you like. For example

```
f[x_]:=Grid[x,Frame->All]
```

Gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, @Nasser.  That works. (The Automatic should be removed when specifying the legends. I should have done that in my post.)